# EditText text cannot be converted to int as there is no text there

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Basically I need to check that the user input from inputET (an EditText) is equal to the integer, correctAnswer. The problem I'm getting is that "" (which is the text in the EditText field) cannot be converted to an int. Is there any other ways of achieving this or catching the error, I've tried the following code which to my understanding asks if the string in the EditText is **not equal to** "". Am i going the right way about this or is there an easier way?

```
// check the input
            if (inputET.getText().toString() != "") {
                if (correctAnswer == Integer.parseInt(inputET.getText()
                        .toString())) {
                    inputET.setText("");
                    newSum();
                }

            }
```

if the user inputs the same int as the correctAnswer integer then the EditText text is reset to "".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `equals()` to compare string. Better, use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`. Or, just use `try-catch` since `parseInt()` may need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if (!inputET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            if (correctAnswer == Integer.parseInt(inputET.getText()
                    .toString())) {
                inputET.setText("");
                newSum();
            }

        }
```

Used `.equals()` method for `String` comparison.

Comment: I believe !=null will be of use as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement I think using TextUtil class will be right way to go for checking the edittext is empty or not.

```
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty( inputET.getText().toString())){
    if (correctAnswer == Integer.parseInt(inputET.getText()
                    .toString())) {
                inputET.setText("");
                newSum();
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

rather tha doing  `if (inputET.getText().toString() != "")` have a try with

```
if (!inputET.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

print the "inputET.getText().toString()" to console and see what it returns. I would hope you need to check the following

```
String str = inputET.getText().toString() 
 if (null!=str && str.trim().equals("")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(inputET.getText().toString()!=null&&!(inputET.getText().toString().isEmpty())){
    //code for mot null
    }else{
    //code for null
    }
```